# Appending a single byte to NSMutableData from Enum

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, casting, enums

I'm trying to easily append bytes (from defined hex enum values) onto an NSMutableData but I'm having some type casting issues, here is the enum:

```
typedef enum {
    eCodePageAirSync            = 0x00,
    eCodePageContacts           = 0x01,
...
    eCodePageRightsManagement   = 0x18
} eCodePage;
```

And here is my method to append the bytes:

```
[self.WBXMLData appendBytes:eCodePageContacts length:1];
```

The issue is being reported as a warning:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'const void *'

Any idea on an easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an underlying integer representation for transfer. If your values are nonnegative, you can use an unsigned type. Since your values range from 0...24 and do fit into one octet, you do not need to worry about endianness in this case. So I would use `uint8_t` for the underlying type as a default in this case.

The other problem is, you need to pass the *address* of the memory to read to `appendBytes:length:`.

Code is written as:

```
const uint8_t value = (uint8_t)eCodePageContacts;
[self.WBXMLData appendBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
                            ^
```

For historical reasons in C, ObjC, and C++, the narrowest representation is not chosen -- so your enum (as declared) is likely an `int`. This means that you can get different values when moving from one platform to another, and endianness also comes into the equation.

You could simplify this by using a strongly typed enum in C++:

```
enum class eCodePage : uint8_t {
    eCodePageAirSync            = 0x00,
    eCodePageContacts           = 0x01,
    ...
    eCodePageRightsManagement   = 0x18
};

const eCodePage value = eCodePage::eCodePageContacts;
[self.WBXMLData appendBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
```

Or `NS_ENUM` in ObjC. Just be sure to choose a fixed width underlying type, rather than a `typedef` which varies by platform/implementation.

Comment: Upvoted (even though I provided a different answer) for the excellent description of enum sizing and its quirks. Although worrying about portability in Objective-C code can be seen as overkill, it is good to always respect the fundamentals.

Comment: `enum class` has other effects in C++ that you might not want. `enum eCodePath : uint8_t` adds the fixed underlying type in C++11 without making the other changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to the data to append. You are passing the raw value instead of a pointer. Try this.

```
uint8_t data = eCodePageContacts;
[self.WBXMLData appendBytes:&data length:1];
```

BTW, I amended the code to use `uint8_t` instead of `eCodePage` based on @justin's excellent advice.

Comment: Yeah, stumbled on this myself just before coming back to the page, thanks!